# alignment of inputs using foundation grid system

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I had written code for two input controls which are of different size.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-7 columns ">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="large-4 columns">
                <label class="left inline">Email</label> <small>*</small>
            </div>
            <div class="large-8 columns">
                <input type="email" class="input-required" placeholder="Example@bluebell.com" required>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="large-5 columns" /></div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-8 columns ">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="large-3 columns ">
                <label class="left inline">Address</label><small>*</small>

            </div>
            <div class="large-8 columns ">
                <input type="text" class="input-required left" placeholder="qewwrrty street">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

first input control(email) within the gird size 7.

second input control(Address) within the gird size 8.

I have attached the screen short of the existing result and expected result in the below image

[image]

and the link to code snippet is attached in the below comment.

Comment: sorry I had forgot to attest the link to code snippet http://jsfiddle.net/nwxemuq5/

Comment: Please always add your code to avoid downvotes.

Comment: I had code snippet shared in jsfiddle so I did not add it here.I would make shure that i would not repeat this mistake of mine again  :) thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/79gnm8bb/2/embedded/result/)

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-8 columns ">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="large-2 columns">
                <label class="left inline">Email</label> <small>*</small>
            </div>
            <div class="large-10 columns">
                <input type="email" class="input-required" placeholder="Example@bluebell.com" required>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="large-8 columns ">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="large-2 columns ">
                <label class="left inline">Address</label><small>*</small>

            </div>
            <div class="large-10 columns ">
                <input type="text" class="input-required left" placeholder="qewwrrty street">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Final Result

[image]

Comment: I wanted the address field to be a bit bigger than email field.

Comment: Foundation sets all imputs `width: 100%;` just give that input a `class` and set `width: 90%;` ie `.small-input{width:90%!important}`   http://jsfiddle.net/79gnm8bb/9/

Answer (score 0):

You missed to close the first `.row` `div`. That's what caused the controls to align incorrectly. [See my fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/79gnm8bb/).

Comment: I want both the "input controls/text" start from the same point. like in the below image <http://i58.tinypic.com/dekzyt.png>

Comment: its a responsive code and thats the reason you see it aligned for a smaller resolution this is how the same code output looks in full screen window http://jsfiddle.net/79gnm8bb/embedded/result/